# QMainWindow wont open in conditional block

Tags: c++, qt

Before opening a QMainWindow a login occurs, and there are 3 possible results, an error, a teacher and a user, if the login result is a user must open a QMainWindow pro user, if he is a teacher his QMainWindow.

```
    LoginDialog login;
    login.exec();

    switch(login.result()){

    case LoginResult::NONE:
        qDebug() << "None";
        break;

    case LoginResult::PROF:
        qDebug() << "Prof";
        break;

    case LoginResult::USER:
    {
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
    }
        break;

    case LoginResult::ERROR:
        Database::Terminate();
        return -1;

    }
```

The problem is that inside the case the window only opens for less than a second and automatically closes, outside the switch, the window shows and stays as it should.

Why does this occur?

Comment: The `MainWindow` object goes out of scope immediately.

Comment: Did you call `app.exec()` after showing the window?

Comment: @MaxiMouse in the end of function `return app.exec()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main window object goes out of scope at the end of the block, and is destroyed. You need to create it with `new` to prevent this:

```
case LoginResult::USER:
{
    auto *w = new MainWindow;
    w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); // to prevent memory leak
    w->show();
}
```

Above pointer variable `w` goes out of scope, but since it is plain raw pointer, this doesn't delete the actual object. Setting the object to delete itself when it is closed is a `QWidget` feature, and is one way to make sure the main window gets cleanly deleted. Not sure if it is a good way for your application, but you can start with it, and then do something else later if needed.

Comment: It worked, but why do you need to create a pointer not to close automatically?

Comment: @IvesTI You need to create a MainWindow object, which doesn't get destructed. Local variables get destroyed at the end of their scope. If the variable is the object, then the object gets destroyed. You need to put it to "free store" AKA "heap" (IOW create it with `new` directly or indirectly) if you want it to not be destroyed at the end of the scope you created it.